# Hibernate @PutMapping update an existing object duplicates related entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

[image]

I have two tables, Goods and Sizes, and many sizes can refer to one good, it will return this JSON:

```
{
    "id": 11,
    "title": "Model2",
    "sex": "WOMAN",
    "manufacturer": {
      "id": 1,
      "manufacturerName": "Ralf",
      "address": "Moscow",
      "telephone": "9-999-999-99-99"
    },
    "manufacturerId": 1,
    "sizes": [
      {
        "size": 35,
        "quantity": 5
      },
      {
        "size": 46,
        "quantity": 4
      }
    ]
  }
```

So when I try update concrete good, for example, add or delete one size, it duplicates all sizes, and from two sizes I will get four

```
sizes": [
      {
        "size": 30,
        "quantity": 2
      },
      {
        "size": 42,
        "quantity": 5
      },
      {
        "size": 41,
        "quantity": 2
      },
      {
        "size": 42,
        "quantity": 5
      }
```

There is my Put method fir update operation

```
@Override
    public void saveGood(Good good) {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        System.out.println(good);
        session.merge(good); //SaveOrUpdate substitute
    }
```

And REST Controller router

```
@PatchMapping("/goods")
    public Good updateGood(@RequestBody Good good) {
        goodService.saveGood(good);
        return good;
    }
```

Relations from entities

```
@JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "good")//Uni-directional reference to size array
    List<Size> sizes;
```

```
@Column(name = "goodid", insertable = false, updatable = false) //Check else
    private int goodId;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "goodId")
    Good good;
```

Comment: you can do: good.getSizes().removeAll().add(..... your new size objects here)
then going to do .save(good)

Comment: Please share your code for both entities Good and Size. Definition is not clear by now.

Answer (score 0):

Add Size ID also in JSON when requesting the action. If ID is present it will update else it will create a new record for the object.